# For Excel how do I create a field that automatically generates a sequential number

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, conditional-formatting, numbering

How do I create a field that automatically generates a unique number when I enter a new record in a table ?

I have a list of numbers in the B column.  I want the numbers in column A to automatically list as 1, 2, 3, 4, .....

BUT

When I insert rows so that I can add additional numbers to the B column, I want the A column to AUTOMATICALLY CORRECT its self and AUTOMATICALLY UPDATE the new empty cells in column A with the sequential numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ......

Is there some sort of CONDITIONAL FORMATTING that I can use?   Formulas do NOT work because the new empty cells in column A dont AUTOMATICALLY FILL themselves.

Comment: It would seem that Access is the only way to accomplish what I want. Excel does not have the capability to auto format numbers sequentially after rows are inserted. :-(

Answer (score 2):

What version of Excel? In 2007 and later you can use an Excel table. All formulas and formatting will automatically be applied to new rows.

Use the formula

=Row()

to create a unique number.

[image]

Then insert a new row above row 3 and you will see:

[image]

If you want the first data row in the table to be a 1, not a 2, use

=row()-1

In Excel 2003 you can use a list. I forget which versions earlier than 2003 support lists, but if you use anything older than 2003 you may want to consider upgrading, anyway. The formula is the same.

Before:

[image]

After inserting a new row:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't (adding hooks to Excel, let's face it, is a HUGE security risk and usually isn't worth the trouble). However, you can get reasonably close by filling in more cells than you can reasonably ever use on the spreadsheet. The details for that are available on this [SuperUser Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289218/how-can-i-autofill-cells-in-excel-using-vba). Just fill the first cell with the formula you mentioned and let the VBA code take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

What is this for? If it is for a database, mysql provides a feature for generating a unique number each time a new record is entered. Or you can use Microsoft Access that has a feature like that.

Answer (score 0):

Question is showing up in `Related` now, in 2021, so here's an updated solution for versions with `Spill` and `SEQUENCE()`:

```
=IF(B1<>"",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B1:B100000),1),"")
```

It is barebones, and can be "slickified" up in any number of ways. The use of `COUNTA()` inside `SEQUENCE()` is an example of that process.

As is, it has to be used with the assumption of no skipped rows and no multiple row entries. Notice the `,""` at the end as the result if the condition tested is `FALSE`:  this is NOT needed as written, but I included it because many might not catch my point with nothing present to point at. The reason is that by using `B1` rather than a range like either `B1:B100000` or a dynamic range that might include more cells in column B than have entries in them, it is never testing any cell that can fail the test. (One could even use the `FALSE` clause to show a phrase in the formula that is never meant to be a real result, but rather to serve as a "comment" in the formula. But if it were MY spreadsheet, I'd simply leave it out.)

It then works like any autoincrement.

You could also combine it with text, or normal number formatting text additions, to create more creative autoincrementing. Lots of ways to modify, slickify, and just generally extend it without any need for Conditional Formatting.

One last point is that inserting a row will initially seem to not adjust the numbers, but the moment the entry in column B's cell is made, the numbers will adjust. So it accomplishes the autoincrementing asked for in the question and DOES succeed at doing what the poster's comment despairs of. Deleting a row works "instantly" because it deletes the column B entry in the same action so the dynamic portion updates at the same moment.